# Normal Force distribution of Prism

Tags: applied-mechanics

On the image below there is a regular prism which is angled by $\alpha$. [image]

The (black) mass m1 applies a torque $M_k$. The mass m2, which is the rest of the Body applies the torque $M_s$ In the opposite direction. The black dot on the bottom right corner is the pivot point.
So i wanted to calculate the normal force distribution on the bottom surface which is completely touching the ground. 
Because the force F1 has to be smaller than F2 right?
My final Goal is to calculate the friction of the prism.
So my question was: Does it matter if i calculate the normal Force by $ F_N = m * g$. Or do i have to integrate $M$ over the whole bottom surface and thus derive the mean of the normal force.

Another problem is: If the prism is accelerated by a another torque $M_a$ is applied. So you definitely cannot calculate the normal force by $m*g$ anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to find the CG of the parallelogram if there is no external torque, just add the overhanging mass of black triangle. This is typically called off-center column or P-Delta loading or a column with both axial and moment loading.

if there is external torque other than the black triangle mass you add it treating a+b as a beam with moment $M_k \ $ applied at the right support of the beam.

So scaling your sketch we assume the height of the part as a, and then you have a base a+b with its CG at $$\bar X =\frac{1/2ab*b/2 +a^2*(b/2+a/2)+1/2ab*(a/2+2*b/2)}{1/2ab+a^2+1/2ab}  $$

So the distribution of the forces on the base will be the sum of the normal weight divided by the base surface which is uniform stress, say q, and the triangular stress, say p, do to overturning moment which is  $ \sigma_{right}=\frac{6M( \bar X- 1/2(a+b))}{ (a+b/2)^2} \quad \sigma_{left}=0   $

So we add these 2 stresses, q and the triangular p together and we get a trapezoid stress surface, with the right hand bigger than left hand stress..

Note: I assumed the depth and mass density as 1.